# Java/JSON DateTime Fields

Tags: java, formatting, timestamp, gson

I have a JSON response which contains a timestamp, but I'm having some issues parsing it to a date object. I'm having the same difficulty serializing it back into the same format as well. I'm using Gson to decode the JSON responses to objects and this is the only spot I'm having a hicup with.

```
    "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1327650052632+0000)\/"
```

I did have a look at the custom serialize/deserialize adapters, but couldn't make heads or tails from it.

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: This seems to be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322541/how-to-convert-a-date-between-jackson-and-gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to understand the adapters (sort of). Here is the code I used:

```
private Gson createGson(){

    JsonSerializer<Date> ser = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
          @Override
          public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext 
                     context) {
            return src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive("\\/Date("+src.getTime()+"+0000)\\/");
          }
        };

        JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
          @Override
          public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
              String tmpDate = json.getAsString();

              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tmpDate);
              boolean found = false;

              while (matcher.find() && !found) {
                   found = true;
                    tmpDate = matcher.group();
              }


            return json == null ? null : new Date(Long.parseLong(tmpDate));
          }
        };


    return new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ser)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, deser).create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has this method .

> formatJSONDate(Date(result.dateFromJSON))

or you may try this regular expression.

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

    if (parts[2] == undefined)
      parts[2] = 0;

    if (parts[3] == undefined)
      parts[3] = 0;

    return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
};
```